# CSS rules don't apply to svg group transform

Tags: svg, transform

I have issue about svg group transform.

I am specifying element styles in css,
like this.

```
#uGroup1 {
transform: translateY(200px);
-ms-transform: translateY(200px);
-moz-tranform: translateY(200px);
-webkit-transform: translateY(200px);
-o-tramsform: translateY(200px); }
```

and I'm creating group with element thru javascript to svg element. It works like charm, but somehow it doesn't get these specs to Matched CSS rules when I search it with inspector.

I realized that after group creation when I change group id to some else and make it back to "right" id, it gets those CSS rules. and it works, but when I create new element with the same idea, it is doing same thing again.

I have many svg groups, and I'd like to work positioning those with transform.

It actually working with some groups. I have groups inside groups.. this might be the issue??

I made element with **uGroup1** and also it was exactly same in css as I showed earlier.

There is some issue with element with capital letters in ID.

Comment: i found **problem and solution**.. 

I made element with **uGroup1** and also it was exactly same in css as I showed earlier.

There is some issue with element with capital letters in ID.

Solution was easy:

ID had to be **ugroup1** without capital letters and css also, after that modification it started working **PERFECTLY**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was easy, just **DONT USER CAPITAL LETTERS ON ID:S**

```
#ugroup1 {
    transform: translateY(200px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(200px);
    -moz-tranform: translateY(200px);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(200px);
    -o-tramsform: translateY(200px); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is wrong to have more than one element with the same ID. That's not a valid XML document, and it's normal for the CSS selector not to match anything but the first element with that ID.

You should instead use class names.

Comment: I don't have elements with same id! I have 8 element with different id, and everyone has to transform to different location. Issue what I had, was that it didn't worked with capital letters. 

I'm adding elements dynamically, so there might be the issue, maybe it is somekind of bug!!

IT WORKS NOW, AFTER NOT USING CAPITAL LETTERS!!